# How to implement generic Function method parameters?

Tags: java, function, generics, java-8, java-stream

Currently I have to define different methods based on the type of the `Function` I want to pass into the method, e.g:

```java
addCustomParameter(orderLinePrefix + "quantity=", concatenateLong(orderLines, OrderPart::getQuantity));
addCustomParameter(orderLinePrefix + "surcharge=", concatenateDouble(orderLines, OrderPart::getSurcharge));
addCustomParameter(orderLinePrefix + "dropship=", concatenateBoolean(orderLines, OrderPart::isDropship));
```

The methods look like this:

```java
@Nonnull
    public <T> String concatenateBoolean(@Nonnull final Collection<T> items, @Nonnull final Function<T, Boolean> mapper)
    {
        return items.stream()
                .map(mapper)
                .map(String::valueOf)
                .collect(joining(","));
    }

    @Nonnull
    public <T> String concatenateLong(@Nonnull final Collection<T> items, @Nonnull final Function<T, Long> mapper)
    {
        return items.stream()
                .map(mapper)
                .map(String::valueOf)
                .collect(joining(","));
    }

    @Nonnull
    public <T> String concatenateDouble(@Nonnull final Collection<T> items, @Nonnull final Function<T, Double> mapper)
    {
        return items.stream()
                .map(mapper)
                .map(String::valueOf)
                .collect(joining(","));
    }
```

How can I refactor the above 3 methods into a single method that will accept any type and return a String?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html

Comment: `<T,V>`and `Function<T, V>` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a wildcard return type for the mapper:

```
@Nonnull
public <T> String concatenateAny(@Nonnull final Collection<T> items, @Nonnull final Function<? super T, ?> mapper)
{
    return items.stream()
            .map(mapper)
            .map(String::valueOf)
            .collect(joining(","));
}
```

Comment: Note that since the OP’s actual use case uses a method reference argument for each invocation, a `Function<T, Object> mapper` parameter would work as well. But using wildcards raises the flexibility regarding already existing `Function` instances.